# Espresso auto generated test fails

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have created a simple test using espresso record were the value of a textview will change with button click from "Hello World" to "Button Clicked!". The code generated is as below

```
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void mainActivityTest() {
        ViewInteraction textView = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.tv), withText("Hello World!"),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withId(android.R.id.content),
                                        0),
                                1),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textView.check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));

        ViewInteraction button = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.button), withText("Button"), isDisplayed()));
        button.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction textView2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.tv), withText("Button Clicked!!"),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withId(android.R.id.content),
                                        0),
                                1),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textView2.check(matches(withText("Button Clicked!!")));

    }

    private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This test will fail on execution giving the following error

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.mysampleapps.mytestproject:id/tv
>   and with text: is "Hello World!" and Child at position 1 in parent
>   Child at position 0 in parent with id: android:id/content and is
>   displayed on the screen to the user)

If I remove the 'childAtPosition' matcher from the test case as

```
public void mainActivityTest() {
        ViewInteraction textView = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.tv), withText("Hello World!"),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textView.check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));

        ViewInteraction button = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.button), withText("Button"), isDisplayed()));
        button.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction textView2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.tv), withText("Button Clicked!!"),
                        isDisplayed()));
        textView2.check(matches(withText("Button Clicked!!")));

    }
```

Now it will work perfectly.

Is this a bug of espresso?

Comment: whenever we auto generate code for testing in espresso there are always some sort of problems and most of the time test fails it is always advisable to edit the code after it is generated. Anyway it also helps you to increase the test coverage and add extra checks if you edit the test cases.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  A generated test should pass.

Comment: Also I looked at the output view hierarchy and noticed that the element of interest in my case was child 0, not child 1 even though the recorder inserted 1.

Comment: Looks like it also depends of API - the same test on the same device behaves differently

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in the code generator for Espresso within Android Studio. I am seeing the exact same thing. While I haven't been able to detect a pattern, I think it may be only counting specific items in a layout (not all of them). I included three guidelines in my layout for example (and these were positioned at the top of the layout), and the count generated for the first view was off by 3.

What I am doing is not using this matcher when I know I don't need it, but in cases where it is useful I am matching the 0-based count to the Nth item in the particular layout. That seems to work (although it is brittle - all I have to do is change the order within the layout file and the matcher now breaks).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to assertions relying on UI Automator hierarchy to establish an element's child position, while actions are relying on Espresso hierarchy. During replay, both actions and assertions are performed using Espresso hierarchy, and as a result, assertions are more prone to failures due to child position mismatches between UI Automator and Espresso hierarchies.

There are several workarounds for this limitation:

1) In Android Studio, in File | Settings, open Build, Execution, Deployment | Espresso Test Recorder and set "Assertion depth" to 1. This way, the added assertions will not rely on child positions to identify the asserted elements (the generated code will look very similar to the example above with the removed 'childAtPosition' matcher). The downside is that an assertion might become too general and might match more than one element.

2) Rely on actions to assert existence of certain elements on the screen, e.g., rather than asserting that a button with a particular text exists on the screen, click on it.

3) Record only actions and add assertions manually into the generated Espresso test.

4) Manually tweak the recorded assertions to use proper child positions.